# Speed up file search in a network path

Tags: batch, batch-file

I am trying to search in a network path inside a folder of 152.000 documents, list of files to be searched is 1500, after 5 hours it has only found 50 documents.

This script was written by another user who helped me. I am trying to see if there is any way to speed it up:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("C:\cleanup\addr.txt") do (
for /r "Z:\Attachments\PDF\" %%b in ("%%a*") do xcopy "%%b" "C:\cleanup\XMLFix\%%~pb" /s
)
pause
```

I think this script is taking the first file name searching through 152.000 documents until it finds matches and then again searches 152.000 documents for the second document and so on.

Can it be written such that it holds all the file names in the buffer and just searches through the 152.000 documents once?

Comment: You have to tell us what exactly you want. A search as complex as what you have now most likely can't be achieved through a simple batch script, but probably has to be done through a vbscript or perhaps using a search tool. If you change the order of the 2 for lines, it will reverse the effect, but the time spend will still be exactly the same.

Comment: I have a list of filenames in a text file (around 1500), now i need to search a shared drive folder having around 152000 documents and copy the matching files to a different folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested, but I think it will work, and it should be relatively fast. Based on your current method taking ~6 minutes per file, I predict this method should take less than 10 minutes to finish. It reads the entire folder hierarchy only once, and then checks the result against all addr.txt entries in one pass.

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\cleanup"

:: Prepare addr.txt to be used as /g option for FINDSTR
(for /f "usebackq delims=" %%F in ("addr.txt") do echo \\%%~nxF) >addr.txt.mod

:: Get a list of full paths to all files in hierarchy
dir /b /a-d /s "z:\attachments\pdf\*" >files.txt

:: Match files in files.txt against files in addr.txt.mod
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('findstr /ileg:addr.txt.mod files.txt') do (
  REM %%F contains the full path of a matching file
  xcopy "%%F" "C:\cleanup\XMLFix%%~pF"
)

:: Delete temp files
del addr.txt.mod files.txt

popd
```

Comment: This is indeed a very good way to eliminate the delay network actions give. Still will go through all files all 1500 times as for can't break out, but it should indeed be quite a bit faster. Good suggestion. +1

Comment: @LPChip - The performance improvement is much more than minimizing network traffic. This would still perform much faster than the original even if file source is from a local drive. And I suspect FINDSTR will break out of its internal (implicit) loop of search strings once it finds a match for a given file, since the output is the same whether one search term matches or multiple match. But without looking at source code I can't prove it.

Answer (score 0):

This will indeed go really slow with a set of for loops for the sole reason that even when it finds a file, it will then continue to search for that same file in the rest of the 152000 documents. So the time spend is 1500x152000.

A VBScript can do this much faster because then you can break out of a loop.

The whole might be optimised even if the filelist can be narrowed down into sections where it will not search everything if you know on beforehand that the files won't be in a specific place, but this might not be necessary.

Lastly, given that doing this over a network will slow down things incredibly, it might be a good thing to copy all the 152000 documents locally and perform the search and copy there.

If you do write a VBScript and you have to perform this over the network, make sure that the VBScript edits the filelist and removes any files from the list it has already found. This will ensure that you can stop the script at any time and resume later.

Although SuperUser is not a scriptwriting service, I'll help you giving what commands you'll need:

```
' Copy files to...
sDestination = "c:\some\path"

' get filenames in folder
sPath = "c:\some\path"
Set fso = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolderContent = fso.GetFolder(sPath)

' open textfile and read its content
set oFileList = fso.OpenTextFile(sFilename, 8, false)

' Loop to go through all files in a folder
For Each oFile In oFolderContent.files
' Loop to go through all folders in a folder
For Each oFile In oFolderContent.folders

'break out of a for loop
exit for

'copy a file
fso.CopyFile oFile, sDestination
```

If this is all too complex, I suggest to get some help at Stack Overflow.